# AWS connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to connect to the Ubuntu VM on AWS, it was working fine but now shows:-

> Permission denied (publickey).

when I run ssh-add /Users/username/Desktop/SSH_KEYS/* , I can connect although i get a warning  WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!

but after connection I get

> 1 update is a security update.
>   System restart required

and each time I reboot my mac machine I need to run ssh-add /Users/username/Desktop/SSH_KEYS/*   again

Also when I am connected if I try  to run

> $ nvidia-smi

I get the following error:-

> Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

Can you please explain what is the reason for all this?

Thanks

Comment: I did sudo chmod 400 <<path to my key>>  and now I do not get   the "WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" but all other issues exist.

Comment: I found that I  unintentionally  deleted the NVIDIA drivers and had to install them again. now I can run nvidia-smi